# Location data me and x not displaying in chrome and safari on mac and ios

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, geolocation, laravel

I have taken over a project called foryrinfo.com and when you visit other pages it works out the distance between you and other venues in the area.

This works on firefox and some safari browser on iphone 5 using ios7. but not other devices and browsers.

Basically I am trying to find out how i can track track where it is breaking. The site is built using Laravel 4. The geo location is done using JS and is passed to another page via ajax.

As the original developer is unavailable I cannot ask him so need to try and debug it myself, but laravel and ajax are not my strong points.

If anyone know how I can start to debug this i'd apprciate it.

***UPDATE:***

The application works in Chrome but only when incognito mode. This I cannot fathom out either

Here is the JS code that was written by the original developer, I have added in alerts so I can follow the processes.

```
if (store.enabled) {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        var now = 0,
            timestamp = 0,
            difference = 0,
            storedLocation;

        if (store.get('location')) {
            storedLocation = store.get('location');
            timestamp = storedLocation.timestamp;
        }

        now = new Date().getTime();

        difference = now - timestamp;
        alert(now +'-'+timestamp);
        if (difference > 1000) {
                alert('diff > 1k');
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                if ( ! storedLocation) {
                    alert('NO STORED LOC.');
                    analytics.track('GeoLocation Updated');
                    store.set('location', position);
                } else {
                    alert('now in the else statement');
                    difference = position.timestamp - timestamp;
                    if ((storedLocation.coords.latitude != position.coords.latitude) || (difference > 6000 || difference < 0)) {
                            alert('storedLocation != position.coords.latitude');
                        analytics.track('GeoLocation Updated');
                        store.set('location', position);
                    }

                    return;
                }

                $.ajax({
                    url: "/location",
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {lat: position.coords.latitude, lon: position.coords.longitude}
                }); // Do AJAX Query and update the server session with location
            });
        }else {
            alert('bleeeerh');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No there are no php errors and from what I see from the console there are no js errors either. For some reason it works in incognito. I found that deleting the cache and cookies etc from devices fixed the safari bug.